# When will Salesforce1 be available in offline mode?

Tags: salesforce1-app, offline

I am wondering how close Salesforce1 is to being available in an off-line mode. For example, if I am a travelling sales rep and my customer is in an area out of coverage for one reason or another, e.g., remote location or cell is down, I wan to be able to still use salesforce to update information such as editing an opportunity or updating a case. This feature (offline edit) is currently not available, instead I have to be connected to the internet. Is this a feature that will be made available and if so when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offline will be available in Summer'14 in read-only mode. Offline for update is on the roadmap for a future release.
This applies to recently viewed records only. There is no sign of an "offline briefcase"-type feature to define what records you want to take offline.

## edit october 2014 : there was no announcement or any sign of new offline capabilities for Salesforce1 at Dreamforce #DF14

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce1 [requirements state](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_mobile_salesforce1_requirements.htm):

> A Wi-Fi or cellular network connection is required to communicate with Salesforce. For the best performance, we recommend using Wi-Fi.

Although you can vote on Salesforce's IdeaExchange for "[Salesforce1 to have the same off line capability as Classic](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kyHXAAY)" - I have found no public statements via Salesforce, or Salesforce reps, saying there is a timeline for adding this feature.