# Salesforce1 Offline - Recommended 3rd Party Solutions?

Tags: salesforce1-app, offline

I'm investigating solutions for a client that would like to have offline SF functionality due to remote locations. From this forum and elsewhere it appears that Salesforce1 will not have the necessary offline read/write synch functionality anytime soon. A quick web search shows just two apps in App Exchange: Pulsar and Formyoula. Does anyone have experience integrating with either of these apps and can share pros and cons?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I would recommend this app - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cwiEAA

Comment: Thanks Jitendra for the recommendation. 

The OS requirements in the documentation lists the latest Win OS as Vista and the Mac OS as 10.5 "Leopard." These are both like 7 years old. The client scenario is for using offline functionality on tablet devices so it would be for Windows 8 (soon to be 9), IOS 8, and Android 4.4.

If you have experience using this app, on what device hardware and what OS was the experience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Youreka](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000E6jHqEAJ), available on the AppExchange, allows you to build forms with a drag and drop editor. It's native to salesforce so it can update your existing salesforce records or create new ones.  Every form you publish can be downloaded in their mobile app and filled in offline, synched when back online. It uses the SmartStore technology mentioned above.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000E6jHqEAJ

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution called SmartStore that is Salesforce's recommended option and one I have seen used very successfully in production a number of times. You can read more about it and integrating it with Salesforce via the Mobile SDK [here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Offline_Apps_with_SmartStore)

Answer (score 1):

For full, customisable apps that support offline CRUD and logic I'd like to point to [MobileCaddy](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q79ZEAQ) (disclaimer: I work for them).

Our SDK extends the Salesforce Mobile SDK, and uses the encrypted SmartStore. It provides a toolkit for rapidly building apps (mobile and desktop) that include full offline support, including master/detail and configurable handling of conflicts/sharing violations etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no direct experience with these products, you should not expect to get a full Salesforce in an "offline mode". More likely they will provide very specific and particular offline functions, likely with a different UI (as you see in the videos and screenshots). Since both of them are free, try them and let us know.

In general terms I would not recommend to use any third party solution for this requirement, since Salesforce has announced to provide it sooner or later natively.

Have a look at this posts:

- [Offline storage for Visualforce pages in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21206/offline-storage-for-visualforce-pages-in-salesforce1)
- [When will Salesforce1 be available in offline mode?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30725/when-will-salesforce1-be-available-in-offline-mode)

As an unfortunate the progress on this feature seems to be bit slower the some of us would prefer.

Comment: Thanks Uwe. I think that for our client they will need to weigh the potential gains in profitability and the benefits of satisfaction of their customer base at the cost of 3rd party apps versus not doing anything and hoping that a native solution comes soon (while safe harbor statements council otherwise). If it costs a little to make a lot, might not be that big of a problem especially if 3rd party apps are subscription anyways.